# How to secure content in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, role-base-authorization

I'd like to use the roles and membership ability of Orchard CMS to limit access to a staff portal in Orchard CMS.  At present there doesn't look like there's an out of the box way to do it.
I've found numerous references to modules that should be able to help out but none seem to work.

Very Simple Permissions is a codeplex item suggested by some that has a dead link nowadays and doesn't seem to exist on codeplex.
Science Project: Quanta destroys my site everytime I try to install it with a missing dll issue, and not sure if its what I need anyways.

Does anyone have any guidance as to how to either: show/hide menu items based on roles using the standard menu system or advanced menu plugin

or

limit content visibility based on roles.  If its a module fantastic, otherwise don't mind getting my hands dirty with some coding but a point in the right way to do this mvc style would be great.  I'm going to presume I need to edit the controller for the menu module to check for current membership and adjust the view data accordingly. I'm moving away from webforms.  slowly. Still getting my head around the framework.

Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still struggling with this, there's a module is called ContentPermissions which is available here:

[gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.ContentPermissions](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.ContentPermissions)

Once installed, you can then add the ContentPermissionsPart to the Content Type you want to secure.

Answer (score 1):

Quanta really is what you want. You are probably missing one of its dependencies. Pete, the author, is also super-active on the CodePlex forums so if you ask there, you'll get an answer.

UPDATE: Orchard 1.5.1, the current version as I'm writing this update, supports content item permissions and menu trimming out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand.  I'll check in with pete and see if he can help me out.  If I can get quanta working it'd be great, it does sound like my one option at the moment.

Comment: I had a chat to peter, it seems like the Quanta module only looks after edit and publish capabilities currently - not view only.  I think i'm looking at implementing my own module.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this Morgan?  I haven't found any examples of anyone being able to accomplish this in Orchard yet, custom Module or not.

Comment: This is now all supported out of the box without requiring and additional module.